# Random texture appears during rendering?

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, artifacts

I am trying to animate a cheaply-made 3D scan of my body a friend rigged for me, and something that is not in the scene shows up in the render. It's like a low-res texture of my own head stuck in a T pose in the middle of the frame. The character has their head facing the ground on the first frame of the shot.
Here is a screenshot of the blender file yesterday night:
[image]

Here is the result of one of the first frames of rendering:

[image]

You can see the top of my head in the foreground, and in the background there's this kind of weird artifact that is not supposed to be there.

Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Could it be something you have hidden in the viewport? Objects hidden in the viewport are still visible in renders.

Comment: that was it thank you! Feeling a bit stupid, lots of troubleshooting just to realize that collections do not work like groups in photoshop. thanks!